# How to place divs relative to a translated div?

Tags: css

I want to move a div up while moving other elements relative to it. Here's an example of what I want to do.

When you press the button, the `div#foo` moves up, while `div#bar` and `div#bar2` stay fixed in place. How can I place `div#bar` and `div#bar2` relative to `div#foo` so that they move up together with `div#foo` whenever it moves up?

```js
document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', function() {
  let foo = document.getElementById('foo');
  foo.className += " up";
});
```

```css
#foo {
  background: gray;
}

#bar {
  background: black;
}

#bar2 {
  background: #222222;
}

.up {
  transform: translate(0%, -100%);
}

.container {
  width: 30vw;
  height: 20vh;
  transition: transform 1s linear;
}

#wrapper {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#btn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="foo" class="container"></div>
  <div id="bar" class="container"></div>
  <div id="bar2" class="container"></div>
</div>
<button id="btn">Move Up<button>
```

Comment: move the whole wrapper, or add the class `up` to all three divs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you use Javascript, you can meanwhile retrieve its height and set negative margin to pul up next element . But it make this element virtuality an height of 0 and it will overlapp anything thats stands before it . Not sure this is what you want (added a few lines to show how it can go off further beside the side effect of flex).

transform, alike position:relative only offsets visually (or transform) the element, but the space it uses remains at the same spot and of the same size.

Example of the idea.

```js
document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', function() {
  let foo = document.getElementById('foo');
  foo.className += " up";
  let mar = foo.offsetHeight;
  foo.style.margin = '-' + mar + 'px 0';
});
```

```css
#foo {
  background: gray;
}

#bar {
  background: black;
}

#bar2 {
  background: #222222;
  color:white
}

.up {
  transform: translate(0%, -100%);
}

.container {
  width: 30vw;
  min-height: 20vh;
  transition: 1s linear;
}

#wrapper {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#btn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="foo" class="container"></div>
  <div id="bar" class="container"></div>
  <div id="bar2" class="container">add <br>a line<br>a line<br>a line<br>a line<br>a line<br>a line<br>a line</div>
</div>
<button id="btn">Move Up</button>
```

Comment: Should probably mention what the amount of the margin is based on.

Comment: @Zohini the height of the element itself . i wrote : #Since you use Javascript, you can meanwhile retrieve its height# and you get here : `let mar = foo.offsetHeight;
  foo.style.margin='-'+mar+'px 0';` reducing the height required by the element virtualy down to zero ;) because it has a negative margin . pulling it up and pulling up what is next/below

Comment: No i meant the use of the height as margin offset relative to the amount of the transform, because any value less or more than 100% wouldn't match

Comment: okay, then you only need to accord it with the % used  `marg * X%` , javascript is involved, so i do not see a real trouble here to adapt it to the transform value. You could even check if that translate value is else than % but px or  vh or else ;)

Comment: yes yes, I only said that it should be mentioned because `you can meanwhile retrieve its height and set negative margin to pull up next element` doesn't tell you why the use of height as margin

Comment: Oki, i see your point ;)